# Getting an error while downloading Sass: 'gem' is not recognized

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to download Sass but it is giving me this in the command prompt: 
'gem" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Do you have ruby installed?

Comment: And is it added to your PATH? Did you succeed to install gems on your environment before?